# Cyrillic font in PDF/A-2u compliant file

Tags: cyrillic, pdf-a

I use Cyrillic characters from Kazakh language(Ә, Ғ, Қ, Ң, Ө, Ұ, Ү, Һ, I) in my thesis, and I need it to be PDF/A-2u compliant. Now I use this code in my .tex file

```
%% Generate PDF/A-2u
\usepackage[a-2u]{pdfx}
\usepackage[russian]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
```

and these characters are displayed correctly in the generated pdf, however it does not conform to PDF/A-2u. Is there any way to solve it, may be use some Cyrillic font, which is compatible with PDF/A format?

I used VeraPDF for verification. It output the following error message:

[image]

From what I have seen, it is because the fonts don't provide ToUnicode table. 
To give you an idea what is in the text, here is a snippet:

"The current Kazakh alphabet has 42 letters: 33from the Russian alphabet and 9 letters that are not in the Russian alphabet.These letters are: Ә, Ғ, Қ, Ң, Ө, Ұ, Ү, Һ, I."

Comment: it would help if you would extend your snippet to a full document demonstrating the issue and mention how you validated the pdf.

Comment: I wrote: show a *complete* (but small) example, don't let use guess what you are really doing.

Comment: You might find it easier to generate a Unicode PDF in LuaLaTeX or XeLaTeX, then convert that over.